# Issue with arm bones

Tags: modeling, rigging, bones

I'm having a problem with the bones in my arms, in that the connection between the upper arm and forearm does not deform the mesh properly when I manipulate it, as if the joint never existed.
[image]

Can someone provide some insight as to why this is happening, and tell me what I can do to solve it?

Comment: have you checked your mesh in Weight Paint mode?

Comment: How do I do this?

Answer (score 1):

So i solved my question. Turns out I needed to subdivide the mesh on the arms as they were too simple, it seems.